# Define pointer to memory with the size of union

Tags: c, pointers, unions

I'm struggling with the demo code like below:

```c
typedef volatile union
{
  unsigned U;
  int I;
  struct
  {
    unsigned some_array:32;
  } B;
} bar;
#define foo (*( bar*) 0xABCDU)
```

I know that `0xABCDU` is some address in memory.
How can I read the `foo` in English?

Comment: `0xABCDU` is a pointer to something. `(bar*) 0xABCDU` is a pointer to `bar`. `*(bar*) 0xABCDU` is the object of (hopefully) type `bar` at address `0xABCDU`. BTW `0xABCDU` is not a hexadecimal number.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It's an *unsigned* hexadecimal literal in C.

Comment: @unwind I obviously need some coffee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`( bar*) 0xABCDU` is `0xABCDU` reinterpreted as a pointer to `bar`.
`*( bar*) 0xABCDU` is dereferenced pointer (a reference if it was C++).

(Outer braces are to prevent it from possible misinterpretation due to operators precedence)

Comment: Not quite: `( bar*) 0xABCDU` is `0xABCDU` reinterpreted as a pointer to `bar`. `*( bar*) 0xABCDU` is the `bar` object itself.

Answer (score 1):

`foo` is the object referenced by the pointer to union `bar`. Pointer to bar has a value converted from the integer constant.